# C - De-interleave Data

Tags: c, sorting, double-pointer

In a C program, I have two double pointers to some float data:

```
float **source;
float **dest;
```

At runtime, the sizes are set and are identical.  I want to copy the data from source to dest, but the source data is interleaved and I want dest to be a non-interleaved copy of the data.  So **source** might look like:

```
1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
```

and on copy I want **dest** to look like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

If I knew the size of the data at compile time I could create arrays of dimmensions MxN and NxM, but I don't.  The 'C pointer' part of my brain hasn't been used in years and is pretty rusty.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If this is about matrix transposition and you can live with one dimentional arrays, there is a simple formula.

Comment: Have you read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com)?

Comment: source and dest are pointers, not numbers, so they can't possibly look like what you describe.  They point at some memory that contains pointers to other memory, and that other memory contains the numbers.  So without describing what those intermediate pointers look like (and how many there are), your question makes no sense.

Comment: Do you mean that you have two arrays-of-arrays of floats, and that you don't know the size of any of the arrays until run-time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sizeof()` operator in order to know the size of any variable. If you would like to perform the dynamic memory allocation at runtime, use `malloc()` function in C.

If you are using C++, you can use the `new` operator.